# How to do facebook auth through a remote proxy

Tags: ruby, facebook, proxy, sinatra

Say I have an app with a Sinatra REST API at http://example.com:4567. With my app I have a designer working on the front-end. Rather than set him up with a local back-end I edit his hosts file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1        local.example.com
```

and his httpd-vhosts.conf as follows:

```
ProxyPass /api http://example.com:4567
ProxyPassReverse /api http://example.com:4567
```

so that API calls are proxied to the remote host. I then create a vhost for local.example.com in apache that maps to his local directory where our front-end repo is. This allows me to give him a remote back-end with a local front-end.

The reason for the subdomain is because we do Facebook authentication which has its restrictive domain policies for auth. We can successfully facebook auth a user and get redirected back to the app, but when attempting to get an access token get a 400 response with the message:

```
{"error"=>{"message"=>"Missing client_id parameter.", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>101}}
```

I believe the client_id is correctly set as it's set in the rack:oauth:client object correctly, and the flow is identical and only fails when the domain is different. The only thought I have is that facebook might not like that the user auth's from local.example.com while the access token is requested from example.com, but my understanding is facebook will authenticate on all subdomains. I've also whitelisted local.example.com on my App.

Any insight or advice into how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't a domain issue, but rather fb_graph, the open source fb api from nov, uses basic auth by default, you need to set auth to something other than ":basic" when you get the access token in order to solve this error.